# Constructor of subclass does not compile

Tags: java

I have an abstract class called Person and a subclass that extends Person called Employee. When i try to compile i get a constructor error. How do i write the constructor in the Employee class so it compile? Please let me know if u need more information on the issue. Thank you.

```
public abstract class Person {    //Person abstract class
   public String firstName;
   public String lastName;
   public char gender;

   public Person(String fname, String lname, char g) { //constructor
      firstName = fname;
      lastName = lname;
      gender = g;
   }
   public abstract void setDefaults();
}

public class Employee extends Person {   //Employee class that extends Person

   public Employee() {    //i thought super(); might solve the problem, but it didnt.
      super();
   }
   public void setDefaults() {}
}
```

Comment: Person does not have a zero argument constructor.  Either create one, or call the super class constructor which does exist.

Comment: Person does not have a empty constructor, here for employee either needs to pass its owner parameters, or allow people constructing Employee to pass them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to pass parameters to your `super()` declaration. Your abstract constructor needs parameters. Parameters in `super()` needs to be the same as your parent constructor. The only way you could use `super()` without any parameters would be if your parent constructor doesn't have any parameters at all.

```
public abstract class Person {    //Person abstract class
   public String firstName;
   public String lastName;
   public char gender;

   public Person(String fname, String lname, char g) { //constructor
      firstName = fname;
      lastName = lname;
      gender = g;
   }
   public abstract void setDefaults();
}

public class Employee extends Person {   //Employee class that extends Person

   public Employee(String fname, String lname, char g) {    //i thought super(); might solve the problem, but it didnt.
      super(fname, lname, g);
   }
   public void setDefaults() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is it

```
public Employee(String fname, String lname, char g) {
    super(fname, lname, g);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `super();` without parameters is not available anymore since you defined your own constructor in Person.

You can fix it by revising the constructor definition in Employee to accept and pass the same parameters as the constructor you created in its superclass Person:

```
public Employee(String fname, String lname, char g) {
    super(fname, lname, g);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling super() which equates to the super class' constructor. But you do not have a default (No argument) constructor. You can do

```
super("John", "Doe", 'M');
```